# highcharts how to set y-axis index for series data(categories),not series(legend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

how to set y-axis index for series data(categories),not series(legend)
http://jsfiddle.net/n7zxvc4q/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['time', 'bytes']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'seconds'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Mb'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [29.9, 71.5],
        name: '192.168.0.1'
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: [14.1, 95.6],
        name: '192.168.0.2'
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: [34.1, 75.6],
        name: '192.168.0.3'
    }]
});
```

I hope  "time" use the left y-axis:seconds(yAxis:0) and "bytes" use the right y-axis:Mb(yAxis:1)

I found other one is not the way I want it,like this
http://jsfiddle.net/141nw7vw/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginRight: 80
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2','192.168.0.3']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'seconds'
        }
    }, {
        title: {
            text: 'Mb'
        },
        opposite: true
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [29.9, 71.5],
        name: 'time',
        yAxis:0
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        data: [14.1, 95.6],
        name: 'seconds',
        yAxis:1
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Highcharts `x/y/zAxis` properties can be assigned only to a series. Categories are only the information how to format axis' labels (their "real" values are their indexes from `categories` array). One series should contain only one type of the data (time or bytes). You should rearrange your data like this (notice that all points have `x` coordinate defined):

```
  series: [
    // time
    {
      data: [
        [0, 29.9]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.1',
      pointPlacement: -0.3,
      color: 'orange'
    }, {
      data: [
        [0, 14.1]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.2',
      color: 'pink'
    }, {
      data: [
        [0, 34.1]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.3',
      pointPlacement: 0.3,
      color: 'blue'

    },
    // bytes
    {
      data: [
        [1, 71.5]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.1',
      yAxis: 1,
      pointPlacement: -0.3,
      color: 'orange',
      showInLegend: false
    }, {
      data: [
        [1, 95.6]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.2',
      yAxis: 1,
      color: 'pink',
      showInLegend: false
    }, {
      data: [
        [1, 75.6]
      ],
      name: '192.168.0.3',
      yAxis: 1,
      pointPlacement: 0.3,
      color: 'blue',
      showInLegend: false
    }
  ]
```

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/rxrys3nx/

I disabled `grouping` to position columns using `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` properties.

I assigned the same color to the mutually corresponding series and used `showInLegend = false` to prevent duplicates in legend.

Then I programmed a legend so that it performs the same action (show/hide) for all series with the common name:

```
    legendItemClick: function(event) {
      var series = this,
        chart = this.chart;

      var isVisible = series.visible;
      chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
        if (s.name === series.name) {
          if (isVisible) {
            s.hide();
          } else {
            s.show();
          }
        }
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

**API references:**

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPadding
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.pointPlacement
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.showInLegend
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick